# cordova-plugin-file can't copy file from gallery to cordova.file.dataDirectory

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to save a video record from the camera to `cordova.file.dataDirectory` but I get a `NOT_FOUND_ERR` when I try to copy the newly created file from the gallery.

I'm using `cordova-plugin-media-capture` to record the video, which then is saved to the user's gallery. But when I get the `FileEntry` using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and try to use `entry.copyTo()` the `NOT_FOUND_ERR` error is thrown.

A cut down / messy version of my code is below:

```
// Capture Video
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(onCaptureSuccess, onError, { limit: 1 });

onCaptureSuccess(mediaFiles: any[]) {

  // Get video Path
  let videoPath = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;

  // Get the actual video file
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(videoPath, entry => {

    // Get the cordova.file.dataDirectory directory entry
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, directoryEntry => {

      // Get / Create the 'videos' directory
      directoryEntry.getDirectory('videos', { create: true }, videoDirectoryEntry => {
    
        // Copy video file (entry) to 'videos' directory
        entry.copyTo(videoDirectoryEntry, 'copiedVideo', copiedEntry => {

          // I should now have a file entry of the copied video, but I don't. I get an error.
          console.log(copiedEntry);

        }, err => {

          console.error(err); // This is where I capture the NOT_FOUND_ERR error

        });
    
      }, onError);
    
    }, onError);

  });

}

onError(error: Error) {
  console.error(error.message)
}
```

Any idea why the file isn't being copied? Do I need to request specific permissions to write to `cordova.file.dataDirectory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, it turns out I needed to request the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions for Android.

At a future date I'll check if any permissions are needed for iOS, but for now I'm happy that it's working for Android.